# How to transform C code to JNI Code

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

I have C code (*testFile*.c) that I want to used in Android App, using JNI.
This code contains pure C code and it has many methods inside. Moreover, it also calls some C header files (*file1*.h, *file2*.h).

For example:
*testFile*.c

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

void myMethod1()
{
    ...
    ...
}
void myMethod2()
{
    ...
    ...
}
void myMethod3()
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Whether I have to transform whole of *testFile*.c to JNI code, or just transform some methods that will i used later (not all of them)?
Should i also transform c code inside header file (file1.h and file2.h), or i just transform c code in testFile.c?

Answer (score 3):

Or if the interface between your Java and C code is extremely simple but the overall process of using jni on Android is unfamiliar, you can more or less merge your C code into the hello-jni example from the ndk.  The point being that you start with something that builds and works, add what you need bit by bit and if you run into issues you can back up and figure out at what stage you broke it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, Sorry, my question is, should i also transform c code inside header file (file1.h and file2.h), or i just transform c code in testFile.c?

Comment: Just as with the C code, that depends on if you need to make adaptations to be compatible with the ndk build environment, android execution environment, activity lifecycle impact on process lifetime, etc.  That's far too broad a question for a specific answer.  Try something and post a new question with a specific problem if you run into one (but do read and understand the activity lifecycle docs, in order to avoid *occasional* errors)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to define your JNI Java side interface and use the automatic generation of c method stubs, `javah`, to generate the c file. In this c file then make calls to the actual c methods `method1()`, `method2()` and `method3()`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javah.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But,
Sorry, my question is, should i also transform c code inside header file (file1.h and file2.h), or i just transform c code in testFile.c?