# how to convert C code to JNI compatible C code?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I searched online and on this site and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454503/how-to-transform-c-code-to-jni-code) link which asks the same question I am about to, but the reply does not seem address the question. Plus one of the referenced links are missing. Basically the question is how do you efficiently and intelligently decide when to use a jni-compatible function to what you have in your C source file. I am familiar with what javah command does, but that command converts JAVA methods into a C header file to be used. What about the methods that are already implemented in a C source file? How can you know if you have to convert them to a JNI version of the method? I am using Android Studio and put in the following code in the .c source file that is in my jni folder of the project:

```
#include "com_example_sansari_usetbt_MainActivity.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define TAG "native-log-tag"
#define LOGI(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGV(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(LOG_TAG, ...) __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
/*
 * Class:     com_example_sansari_usetbt_MainActivity
 * Method:    usetbt
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_sansari_useqsee_MainActivity_Usetbt
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    int fd;
    int rc = 0;
    char *rd_buf[16];
    //(*env)->printf("<1>%s: entered\n", argv[0]);
    printf("<1>: entered\n");
    fd = open("/dev/tbt", O_RDWR);
    LOGI(LOG_TAG,"This is a log test");
    LOGV(LOG_TAG,"This is a log test");
    LOGE(LOG_TAG,"This is a log test");
    //(*env)->fd;
    //return;
    if ( fd == -1 ) {
        perror("<1>open failed");
        rc = fd;
    }
    printf("<1>: open: successful\n");
    /* Issue a read */
    rc = read(fd, rd_buf, 0);
    //I need to find what fd is and then use command completion to pick a jni finction. rd-buf seems to be jstring, and 0 seems to be int
    rc = (*env)->GetString
    if ( rc == -1 ) {
        perror("<1>read failed");
        close(fd);
    }
    printf("<1>: read: returning %d bytes!\n",rc);
    close(fd);
    (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hi From Usetbt version 2");
}
```

And ndk-build compiles the project, but I do not get the result I am looking for. That is, the normal C version of the code which I compiled with NDK opens the driver and is able to interface with it, but this does not do the same. I do not see the result of the print statement in the kernel logs that is. I am not asking for someone to convert the above code; rather show me the way to know which of the above lines need to be converted, and what is the best way to do it please. I have read a number of items about this, and I am quickly coming up to speed, but if you can describe at a high level how
this conversion is done, please advise. I do have a copy of Java Native Interface and a number of Android texts and am going through them as fast as possible.
Thanks

Comment: _"How can you know if you have to convert them to a JNI version of the method?"_ That should be easier to determine if you rephrase the question you ask yourself: _Does this C function need to be called from Java? (i.e. not through some other C function, but directly from Java)_

Comment: I knew someone is going to say this. But the issue is I can not even verify that any of the C statements are being executed. I do realize if I need any of the data structures from C source in my Android files, I need to use the API. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but that makes no sense to me. Why would you write a function without knowing under which circumstances it will be called? Anyway, you should use the logging functions in `<android/log.h>` instead of printf. Redirecting stdout to logcat might also work, but that's not something I've tried.

Comment: I know what the C source file does; the problem is when I add it to my Android project it does not do that same thing. Specifically, it does not generate the kernel log message that tell me it opened the device driver successfully.

Comment: I compiled the C source file with NDK outside of an Android Project and it does what I want. I just want to put it in an app so I can run it faster by clicking the icon, rather than from the command line. I also want to be able to add different buttons for activating different methods such as ioctl, and ...

Comment: I got the header file in there. I am glad you mentioned it; I'll update the source file. I put in some TAGs and macors for logging, but they do not show up in logcat, adb, or /kmsg :-(

Comment: How about this? Do you want me to post the C source file that works and what is in my .c file of JNI folder?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `fflush(stdout);` after your printf.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085213/1715829).

Comment: @Buddy-Thanks I am trying it now.

Comment: @Buddy- Thanks. I think I need to update something else also. I do not see any output or log messages.